# Bash script to go to directory and perform commands gives "Command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Script

```
!/bin/bash

source .bashrc && cd htdocs && drush status
```

I run `bash -x script` and get `script: line 3: drush: command not found`

If I run same commands manually one by one, the last command works fine.

Script permissions `-rwxrwxr-x`.

(on shared hosting, limited abilities)

Comment: (1) `#!/bin/bash`, not `!/bin/bash`. (2) Where does drush come from? Run `type drush` outside the script, and provide the answer as an edit to the question.

Comment: Note that your script should probably be modified to rely less on relative paths. Right now it'll only work if run in a directory that contains your `.bashrc` and has a directory named `htdocs`. At minimum, you should probably have a `cd "$HOME"` in front of the remainder of its contents (though having a script source `.bashrc`, which is generally intended for *interactive* shell configuration, is not a good idea in and of itself either).

Comment: I'm halfway guessing that your `drush` command is an alias. Noninteractive shells don't honor aliases -- but either way, the `type` command I provided earlier will clear that up.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry for a typo, I have # in the script. And yes, it's an alias that in order to make it work I have to run `source .bashrc` every time I connect via SSH, so how do I run this?

Comment: The generic answer we have in the #bash IRC channel re: aliases is "if you have to ask, use a function instead". Replace `alias drush='whatever'` with `drush() { whatever "$@"; }`.

Comment: BTW, it's... unusual... for you need to source your `.bashrc` manually on an interactive shell. Can't tell you why it's happening without inspecting the details -- could be your shell isn't actually bash; could be it's being invoked with `--rcfile` or `--init-file` or `--norc` or under the name `sh` rather than `bash`; could probably be something else I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, drush does a lot of things https://github.com/drush-ops/drush e.g. in my case I need to write a  script of some sort that runs certain drush commands, multiple ones to check for status, backup website database, run security updates for core of Drupal website, etc. And use that same script for dozens of websites on different servers. All that to save tons of time from running every command manually. @CharlesDuffy it's just some shared hosting, I got no root, client doesn't care.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow either. You have an alias. Replace that alias with a function. If you're not clear on how to do that, *provide the actual alias definition* (or the `type` output I asked you to [edit] into the question on my very first comment) and we can help.

Comment: you're right, looks like it's working if I set it as `php $HOME/full/path/drush.php status`, so I should use that for all commands instead of alias.

Comment: BTW, best practice is to quote your expansion -- `php "$HOME"/full/path/drush.php status`, f/e. Probably won't matter for `$HOME` unless you have an unusual `IFS` value, but better safe than suddenly having surprising bugs if using `IFS=/` to cause string splitting / joining to operate on that value.

Comment: `drush() { php "$HOME"/full/path/drush.php "$@"; }` is a function definition equivalent to `alias drush='php ~/full/path/drush.php'`